# converting old ggplot2 code to new in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use following code from https://gist.github.com/adamwespiser/3077780 :

```
theme_publish <- function(base_size = 12) {
    structure(list(
    axis.line = theme_blank(),
    axis.text.x = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8 , lineheight = 0.9, vjust = 1),
    axis.text.y = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, lineheight = 0.9, hjust = 1),
    axis.ticks = theme_segment(colour = "black", size = 0.2),
    axis.title.x = theme_text(size = base_size, vjust = 1),
    axis.title.y = theme_text(size = base_size, angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0.3, "lines"),
    axis.ticks.margin = unit(0.5, "lines"),
    legend.background = theme_rect(colour=NA),
    legend.key = theme_rect(colour = "grey80"),
    legend.key.size = unit(1.2, "lines"),
    legend.text = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8,family = "sans"),
    legend.title = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, face = "bold", hjust = 0),
    legend.position = "right",
    panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA),
    panel.border = theme_rect(fill = NA, colour="grey50"),
    panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
    panel.margin = unit(0.25, "lines"),
    strip.background = theme_rect(fill = "grey80", colour = "grey50"),
    strip.text.x = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8),
    strip.text.y = theme_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = -90),
    plot.background = theme_rect(colour = NA),
    plot.title = theme_text(size = base_size * 1.2),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines")
    ), class = "options")
}
```

I am trying to use this function as follows:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp,size=wt))+geom_point()+theme_publish()
```

However, it does not work and there are errors like:

```
Error: Use 'element_text' instead. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.1)
```

Can I correct these all at once or do I need to change every line to new code format? Thanks for your help.

Edit: 
According to comments from @Metrics, I tried to replace all 'theme_' with 'element_', change theme_segment to element_line, load the grid package, change the class to 'theme'. The modified function is:

```
theme_publish <- function(base_size = 12) {
    structure(list(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8 , lineheight = 0.9, vjust = 1),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8, lineheight = 0.9, hjust = 1),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.2),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = base_size, vjust = 1),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = base_size, angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0.3, "lines"),
    axis.ticks.margin = unit(0.5, "lines"),
    legend.background = element_rect(colour=NA),
    legend.key = element_rect(colour = "grey80"),
    legend.key.size = unit(1.2, "lines"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8,family = "sans"),
    legend.title = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8, face = "bold", hjust = 0),
    legend.position = "right",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour="grey50"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.margin = unit(0.25, "lines"),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey80", colour = "grey50"),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = -90),
    plot.background = element_rect(colour = NA),
    plot.title = element_text(size = base_size * 1.2),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines")
    ), class = "theme")
}
```

But now I get the error:

```
Error in if (attr(newtheme, "complete")) return(newtheme) : argument is of length zero
```

I am not able to make out from which line it is coming from.

Comment: replace all `theme` with `element` and see whether it works.

Comment: you need to use `element_line` instead of `element_segment`

Comment: did you load the grid package?

Comment: see the changes here: https://github.com/wch/ggplot2/wiki/New-theme-system

Comment: did you change `class`  to `"theme" `?

Comment: On doing that I get: Error in if (attr(newtheme, "complete")) return(newtheme) : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: May be this can help: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/587

Comment: Yes, you need to go through each line, check if it is in accordance with the documentation, and change it if it is not.